# Prove that $\forall s, t \in \mathbb Z_+$ if $\le t$ and $2 \binom{t}{s-1}=\binom{t}{s},$ then $3|(t+1)$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, induction

So for this question $$\text{Prove that }\forall \text{ s, t } \in \text{ positive integers, if s  }\le t\text{ and 2} \binom{t}{s-1}=\binom{t}{s}, \text{ then } 3|(t+1)$$

Where should I start? I think induction. But do I strongly induct? The base case should be t=1 yes? Are there more base cases? For the inductive step, I do not have idea how to do inductive step, sadly. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: You cannot apply induction since such an $s$ may not exist for each $t$, e.g. $t=3$. A direct proof would make use of the definition of those binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$ \frac{2 {t \choose s-1}}{t \choose s} = \frac{2s}{t+1-s}$$

If this is $1$, then $t+1= \ldots$